# Why is Gradle taking so long to build?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

My Gradle build is taking between 1 minute and 2 minutes and I'm uncertain what's going on. On Event Log I see a single entry most of the time

> Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:assembleDebug]

I have no idea what this task is doing, I've checked `work offline` setting hoping this to make a difference but I had no luck.

Answer (score 3):

Pass the `--profile` option to Gradle to profile build execution time and generate a report in the `<buildDir/reports/profile` directory. For more information see the docs about [Profiling a build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:profiling_build).

Comment: Personally, I'd do this by running Gradle (via its wrapper) form the command line. But as you seem to be using Android Studio only, go to *File* -> *Settings* -> *Build, Execution, Deployment* -> *Compiler* and add `--profile` to *Command-line Options.*

Comment: Not seeing any output using `--profile` on directory `buildDir`. I'll take a deeper look into this, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Gradle build time depends on a lot of factors and may get slower as the codebase of your project grows, you add more third-party dependencies.

For instance if you use Google Play Services dependencies, you can break those apart and only use the specific dependency you need.

For example try to use

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'

instead of

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'

This is just an example which is misused by a lot of people but as I said it's usually based on how large your codebase is. 
And obviously the hardware configurations, your machine have..